# Blender texture viewport black?

Tags: texturing, 3d-view

I just started and this is probably a really easy question, but when I click on my cube and try to view my texture the viewport is black and doesn't give me the normal texture preview.

Anything I'm doing wrong?

See attached images of an example of my black viewport.

[image]

Comment: oh I'm using MacOS Catalina and Blender 2.78

Comment: Could you try switching to cycles?
And why are you on 2.78?

Comment: Because only 2.78 works with creating items for the Sims 4 haha. Cycles doesn't do anything either.. I downloaded 2.8 and works fine, must be a MacOS Catalina thing?